# Two meanings of word "government"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity, politics, hyponyms

I noticed that in English language "government" can mean "any legal authority" or it can mean specifically "the executive branch of power (like Cabinet of Ministers)". What is primary meaning, that is assumed, when context is not given?

Comment: No word has any meaning without context.  Do you have an example of the kind of use of "government" you're thinking of?

Comment: "The government" usually means the central political machinery: parliament, the civil service, etc. But there is government at all levels: local government (county, city, town and parish councils) and smaller, even the governers of schools.

Comment: Nothing means anything without context. "Apple" can be a computer company, a record company, a fruit, a genus of tree, and likely any number of other things. If I just run up to you and shout the word "APPLE!", which one do I mean?

Comment: Ugh? "No word has meaning without context." Rubbish! If I shout **FIRE** you damn well know what that single word means. Just as when someone says "I hate this government" you know what is meant.

Comment: "I hate this government" sounds like a context to me.  The word "government" written on a blank piece of paper sitting on my desk means nothing.  Likewise, when someone asks what does "government" mean, there's either no answer, or else the answer is all the possible meanings.

Comment: @Juhasz OP is asking what is *usually* meant.

Comment: Before we can answer, the OP should look in a dictionary, and add what was fond to the question.

Comment: Note that the US has a clear distinction between State government and the Federal government that doesn't exist in other English speaking countries.

Comment: Not to mention "government" can also mean the act or process of governing. Context is definitely required.

Comment: @WeatherVane If it's a movie theatre in which everybody is carrying a loaded gun, and there's somebody tied up in front of the movie that's being played—don't you think that *Fire!* could be taken ambiguously? How are you to know if it's the verb or a declaration of an event? Is the person to be shot or have flames broken out?  Context *always* makes a difference and is *always* necessary. It's simply that in your example you've already *assumed* what the context is.

Answer (score 0):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/80321?redirectedFrom=government#eid) , in stating the many meanings and usages of the word 'government', begins with what I assume the OED views as the 'primary meaning' :

> I. General senses, relating to actions with direct or controlling influence, or to the exercise of personal authority.
>    1.
>
> a. **The continuous exercise of authority over a person, group, etc.; guardianship, protection; control.**

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/government) seems to agree :

> 1 : the act or process of governing
>   specifically : **authoritative direction or control**

Thus, with regard to your query, if one were in doubt as to the meaning of the word when used by a writer or speaker, one might well be wise to assume this meaning, primarily.

Answer (score 0):

The US and the UK are different in this regard.  In the US, the default meaning is "any legal authority." I have the impression, from listening to BBC news programs, that in the UK, it means the "executive branch of power."  (In the US, the executive branch of power is called "the administration" or "this administration.")